# A supposed incorrect theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi i'm new here and here's my question:

Suppose $A\subseteq$$P(A)$. Prove that $P(A)\subseteq$$P(P(A))$.

I am using the book How to prove it by Velleman and i was wondering if anyone had a link to the soluions manual pdf if there ever was one?? I've googled it but it seems that no one has worked out the exercises and posted the solutions online and if they have it's not for all the chapters. It's a great book and i'd really appreciate it.

Also, i understand that a set cannot be a subset of its powerset so i don't understand what the question is tring to prove??

Comment: Let $A = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset\},  \{\{ \emptyset\}\},\dots\}$. Then $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, so a set **can** be subset of its powerset.

Comment: Oh didn't think of it that way, thanks and do you know where i could get the solutions manual for the book??

Comment: More generally, if $A\subseteq X$ then $P(A)\subseteq P(X)$. Now substitute $P(A)$ for $X$. By the way, the empty set is a subset of its powerset. You must be thinking of the fact that $P(A)$ cannot be a subset of $A$.

Comment: Easier example that a set **can** be a subset of its power set: $\emptyset \subseteq P(\emptyset)$.

Comment: @azimut Of course, but I wanted a bit more than a trivial case.

Comment: @PeterPkKamau [This guy](http://technotes-himanshu.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/how-to-prove-it-retrospection.html) has some. I don't think there is anything official, but you can always ask the author.

Comment: I already checked them out, but they aren't for the chapters i'm currently working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with a set being a subset of its powerset. Sets with that property are called transitive and all ordinals satisfy that property.

Assume $A\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $z\in\mathcal{P}(A)$. We just have to show $z\in\mathcal{PP}(A)$.

Since $z\in\mathcal{P}(A)$, $z\subseteq A$ and with our hypothesis $z\subseteq A\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A)$.

$z$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and that just means $z\in\mathcal{PP}(A)$.

Comment: Ok, so should that z be arbitrary or should there just be at least a $z\in$$A$ such that if $z\in$$A$ then $z\in$$P(A)$??

Comment: Arbitrary, the proof holds for every element of P(A), which is what you need for P(A) to be a subset of P(P(A))

Comment: Ok, so should that z be arbitrary or should there just be at least a $z\in$$A$ such that if $z\in$$A$ then $z\in$$P(A)$?? Because i understand that the definition of subset in this case is $\forall$$z$$\in$$A$($z$$\in$$P(A)$) which assumes that z is an arbitrary element of A.

Comment: But that isn't true since suppose A = {1,{1},{{1}},{{{1}}} ...} then P(A)={{1},{{1}},{{{1}}}...} but 1 isn't an element of P(A) and so it doesn't hold for all elements of A

Comment: But you said suppose A is a subset of P(A), and z is arbitrary yep.

Comment: But i don't see how $A$ can be a subset of $P(A)$ since for every element of $A$ the element will be converted into a set when it gets to $P(A)$ and so i'm worried about the elements that are not sets like 1, and that's why i don't see how you can suppose something that isn't true??

Comment: If $A$ isn't a subset of $P(A)$ then your theorem doesn't have anything to say, so don't worry about the sets that aren't subsets of their powersets. Are you still unsure that any sets satisfy $A\subset P(A)$? Even if none did the theorem would still hold.

Comment: I understand that if you suppose something then you are assuming that its true even though it might be false, so that you can prove something that has the same structure as the hypothesis that you supposed. So it's like supposing something false then proving that it's false. So philosophically, is a set a subset of its powerset??

Comment: Which set? That should make it clearer

Comment: I have a problem understanding that any set is a subset of its powerset based on the example i gave above, so if there's another easier explanation then i'd really like to see it!!

Comment: They gave examples in the comments to the question